# Comparing 2 files with a for loop in bash

Tags: bash, variables, for-loop, awk

I am trying to compare the values in 2 files. For each row in Summits3.txt I want to define the value in Column 1 as "Chr" and then find the rows in generef.txt which have my value for "Chr" in column 2.
Then I would like to output some info about that row from generef.txt to out.txt and then repeat until the end.
I am using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $(cat Summits3.txt)
do
Chr=$(echo "$i" | awk '{print $1}')   
awk -v var="$Chr" '{
if ($2==""'${Chr}'"")
print $2, $3
}' generef.txt > out.txt
done
```

it "works" but its only comparing values from the last line of Summits3.txt. It seems like it not looping through the awk bit.

Anyway please help if you can!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please post sample Input_file and expected output sample file in code tags too in your post.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be looking for something like this:

`awk 'FNR == NR {a[$1]; next} $2 in a {print $2, $3}' Summits3.txt generef.txt > out.txt`

Basically you read column one from the first file into an array (array index is your chr and the value is empty character) then for the second file print only rows where the second column is in the index set of the array. `FNR` row number in file that is currently being processed, `NR` row number of all processed rows so far. This is a general look-up command I use for pulling out genes or variants from one file that are present in the other.

In your code above it should be appending to out.txt: `>> out.txt`. But you have to make sure to re-set out.txt at each run.

Comment: This is the traditional, simple, and nearly always correct solution. If the OP had bothered to search for "join chromosome columns" they would have found dozens or hundreds of variations of this solution on this site alone.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using external scripts inside a loop (that is expensive), the first thing we see is that you redirect your output to a file from insside the loop. The output files is recreated each time, so please change inte append (`>>`) or better move the redirection outdide the loop.
When you want to use a loop, try this

```
while read -r Chr other; do
   cut -d" " -f2,3 generef.txt | grep -E "^${Chr} "
done < Summits3.txt > out.txt
```

When you want to avoid the loop (needed for large inputfiles), an `awk` or some combined command can be used.
The first solution can fail:

```
grep -f <(cut -d" " -f1 Summits3.txt) <(cut -d" " -f2,3 generef.txt)
```

You only want matches of the complete field `Chr`, so starting at the first position until a space ( I assume that is the field-sep).

```
grep -f <(cut -d" " -f1 Summits3.txt| sed 's/.*/^& /') <(cut -d" " -f2,3 generef.txt)
```